# Java Max Heap Memory - Code is Stopping?

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, paging

I am loading a big text file into memory (filling a class with a table to hold all the data). Text files range from several MB to 1 GB. However when loading a text file around 100 MB my java app running on windows 7 x64 basically just stops in the middle of reading the text file at about 40%. I am checking for free memory as I load each line.

The last output from println before the code stops reading the text file is

Total Memory: 688128
Free Memory: 86032
Used Memory: 602095

In task manager java.exe is consuming about 838 MB of Ram.

Anyway I can page memory to/from disk or increase the max memory? I will be running the application on multiple systems.

Comment: Could your system be [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29)?  Continuously trying to find more memory, and paging things to disk or doing a full GC that only releases a small amount of memory before the system has to start looking for memory again.  Running with `-verbose:gc` should tell you if the GC is thrashing and `top`/Windows process manager should tell you about excess paging.

Comment: You might be better off with a database such as MongoDB, Redis or even a distributed ehcache or gridgain.

Comment: Consider using `Stream`s and `Reader`s, rather than loading the whole file into JVM. You have to try to process the file on-the-fly.

Comment: Concerning the current situation: try running `jstat` with different parameters, e.g. `jstat -gcutil`. Here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html you can read the different options.

Comment: Also would be interesting to know the JVM startup parameters (specifically the memory options)

Comment: If you cannot increase the JVM's startup parameters, your options would be: either to decrease the storage you need when you read it in, or to push some of it back to disk. If you do the latter, you should probably look into a simple Java caching library that does most of the work for you.

Comment: Which is the JVM command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError Max file size limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35930340/xxheapdumponoutofmemoryerror-max-file-size-limit)