# Usage of XX:HeapDumpSegmentSize and XX:SegmentedHeapDumpThreshold

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments, heap-dump

I've encountered a problem that dumping a heap fails due to the following message:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to /usr/local/webapp/logs/java_pid<MY_PID>.hprof ...
Dump file is incomplete: file size limit
```

I've found a similar QA here: [XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError Max file size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35930340/xxheapdumponoutofmemoryerror-max-file-size-limit), but it just refers to options we can use to solve this problem, not how to use them. Searching on the web doesn't help me either because there's little information on these. To make matters worse, I cannot easily test them because the problem seldom occurs.

I found that my application reached its max heap size(8GB) and tried to dump the heap, but failed due to the error above and the dumped file size is only 2.2GB, which seems incomplete and any tools (like jhat, jconsole, jvirtualvm) can't open it.

How can I avoid the problem by using options `XX:HeapDumpSegmentSize` and `XX:SegmentedHeapDumpThreshold`?

#### Environment

- Java `1.8.0_71`
- Options that seem to be relevant:

  - `-Xmx8196m`
  - `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`
  - `-XX:HeapDumpPath=$LOG_DIR`
  - `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"`

Comment: Which Java version are you using? What's not working for you using the examples on your provided link? What error do you get using the mentioned options?

Comment: @SubOptimal Thank you for commenting. I'm using Java of `1.8.0_71`. The examples of the link just refers to the existence of the options, not the way to use them. I haven't used them because I don't figure out whether to make them larger or smaller.

Comment: Maybe the `kill -9 %p` is executed before the task for `HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` has been finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HeapDumpSegmentSize` and `SegmentedHeapDumpThreshold` are developer options, they cannot be changed in production JVM. These options will not help you anyway, because they are **not about splitting** heap dump into multiple files, but rather about creating multiple segments inside **one file**.

Make sure that `ulimit -f` is large enough to create 8G files.

Comment: I understand the options couldn't help me out. Actually, the application has created dump files over 8GB(around 9GB) several times, so I'm not sure why it fails this time. I've checked `ulimit -f` and it was `unlimited`. Any more suggestions would be welcomed very much, but your answer is appropreate to my question though...